method for Calculating / Retrieving CPU Clockspeed in C?
For an assignment, I've been trying to work on a project to inspect and retrieve system information on Linux either in pure C, or inline ASM. A bit of a problem I'm having now is actually retrieving the clockspeed.
I initially attempted to just read from __cpuid:
__cpuid(0x80000002 + i, eax, ebx, ecx, edx);

I do not believe on AMD CPUs, the Clockspeed is incorporated in this string. Now, I am using rdtsc to retrieve a pretty accurate figure, but the more I reduce the busy-wait loop's time, the more accuracy I am losing. So far this is what I've come up with:
static inline uint64_t rdtsc() {
    unsigned int lo, hi;
    asm volatile ("rdtsc" : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi));
    return ((uint64_t)hi << 32) | lo;
}
void calculate_cpu_clock_speed() {
    uint64_t start, end;
    struct timespec ts_start, ts_end;
    double elapsed_time;

    // Get TSC and time at start
    start = rdtsc();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts_start);

    // (~1 ms)
    do {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts_end);
        elapsed_time = (ts_end.tv_sec - ts_start.tv_sec) +
                       (ts_end.tv_nsec - ts_start.tv_nsec) / 1e9;
    } while (elapsed_time < 0.001);  

    end = rdtsc();

    (cycles per second -> Hz -> GHz)
    double clock_speed_hz = (end - start) / elapsed_time;
    double clock_speed_ghz = clock_speed_hz / 1e9;
    
    printf("%.1f0 GHz\n", clock_speed_ghz);
}

Is there any chance at getting this faster?

Just read it from /proc/cpuinfo

@Shawn How about turning that into an answer?

Note that modern systems use dynamic frequency scaling; the CPU clock is adjusted based on current work load.  If you run a busy waiting loop, this is interpreted as load and the CPU clock is sped up.  This would explain your inconsistent results: with short loops, the amount of work you do is too little to trigger a clock adjustment.  With somewhat longer loops, it is triggered some times, and with long loops, always.

@Shawn I know that would be possible, however apart of this project is understanding hardware, and architecture, hence why I prefer to do this without reading from a file.

The TSC frequency isn't always the same as the stock non-turbo frequency from the vendor string, aka the "sticker" frequency you see advertized.  For example, my Skylake has a TSC frequency of 4008 MHz, but the vendor string is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz.  (And the max turbo without overclocking is 4.2GHz).  On lower-power mobile CPUs, core clock frequency is  even more distantly related to TSC or vendor string, rarely operating at the slow worst-case frequency.

See How to get the CPU cycle count in x86_64 from C++? and BeeOnRope's comments re: i5-1035G4 with a TSC frequency of 1.5 GHz but a sticker frequency of 1.1 GHz.  1.5 GHz is the TDP-up frequency, but Bee's laptop uses it in the standard 15W TDP configuration.  So anyway, even disabling turbo doesn't necessarily make the TSC frequency anywhere near the actual core clock.  Anyway, your question title asked about the "CPU clockspeed"; if that's what you want, then the TSC is not useful on CPUs since about 2006.

Thanks @PeterCordes, any idea how one might be able to more accurately retrieve the clockspeed information without doing reading from a filesystem? I am trying to find something more universal, even doing inline assembly would work for me.

You can't read the P-state / turbo management MSRs or whatever from user-space since rdmsr is a privileged instruction.  On bare metal or in kernel code you could find out what the current CPU's clock speed is; that's how the Linux kernel code that generates /proc/cpuinfo and various /sys files on the fly know what to put.  Programs like turbostat read that.

Thanks, I'll take a look at how the kernel does it.

Without any virtual-filesystem acccess, a user-space process under Linux could use perf_event_open to configure a counter (fixed or programmable) for the cycles aka (which typically maps to an event like cpu_clk_unhalted.thread), with the kernel configured to allow user-space to run rdpmc.  Then you could run a busy loop (so the clock doesn't halt for most of that time) and calculate how many core clock cycles you had over a certain wall-clock interval from clock_gettime (or from an rdtsc delta after finding the TSC frequency),  Maybe any-task like perf stat -a but one core

The following C program retrieves the current frequencies of -- at most 8 -- individual CPU cores from the sys filesystem. Perhaps this is a valid solution to your problem.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define CORES         8
#define INDEX_CPU_ID 27
#define PATH "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq"

int main() {
    char path[] = PATH;

    for(int i=0; i<CORES; i++) {
        path[INDEX_CPU_ID] = i+'0';
        FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");
        if (fp == NULL) continue;

        unsigned int freq = 0;
        switch(fscanf(fp, "%u", &freq)) {
        case EOF:
            perror(path);
            break;
        case 0:
            fputs("not a number\n", stderr);
            break;
        default:
            printf("CPU %d frequency: %u kHz\n", i, freq);
            break;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return errno;
}


You don't use the PATH_LEN macro you hard-code, and you don't need it anyway; you could use sizeof(PATH).  Or better just use PATH as an initializer like char path[] = PATH; to let the compiler invent the copying to the stack.  (Or make it static).

To extend this to more than 9 cores, you could use a format string for sprintf and stop once fopen fails.  (Assuming valid core numbers are always contiguous.)  In the shell, I'd grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq to print the filename:contents for each core.  (I often actually use grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo since that's easier to type, and it's only one file to open and read, although a lot of kernel code runs to generate the cpuinfo contents.)

fscanf only sets errno on a read error, not for the more common cases of input or matching failure. Your validation is good, but you may want to output the error with fputs() or fprintf() to stderr instead of relying on perror(). This is more a general comment rather than to anything specific to the cpu cores retrieval. You can also avoid the strcpy() by simply initializing path to your string in main(), e.g. char path[] = PATH;.

Dear  Peter Cordes and David C. Rankin, thank you for pointing out some issues in my code. I have addressed several of them and updated it accordingly.

didn't see your reply since you didn't @ notify me or @DavidC.Rankin .  Good edit, big improvement.  Your error() function is unused, your main just calls perror.  If fscanf doesn't return 1, you shouldn't call printf with the uninitialized freq.  It's extremely unlikely for the open() and read() to succeed on that path but not produce an ASCII string of a decimal integer, but if you want to handle it, int conversions = fscanf(...), and maybe strerror(errno) if the return value is negative, otherwise your own error message like "not a number".  And yes, use fputs(stderr).

Dear @PeterCordes thank you again for pointing out several issues with my posted code. I have addressed them and updated the code. I stay tuned for further pointers. :-)

case EOF will happen on an empty file.  So maybe if (ferror(fp)) { perror(path); break; } // else empty or whitespace-only file, fall through into conversion-failure case.  Man, stdio error handling is surprisingly obnoxious.  No wonder it's popular to avoid scanf / fscanf, only maybe using sscanf after reading a line some other way.

the idea was to achieve this without a file system, i.e "Calculating". Such as from TSC. Which was previously discussed I believe in the previous by @PeterCordes in the previous discussion
